# how to do Multiple Excel formulas into one sting

Tags: excel

What im trying to do im not sure if it's possible. I want to use entire columns as there are multiple different address in both sheets, so I need date to be pulled based of the address. `Sheet 1 = CSH Test` `Sheet3 = CSH Overview` I want to do the following: In `sheet3 column 4` header is **Address** it shows **address**, in `column 7 Header Epic Equipment`.

I want it to pull a **percentage** of new vs installed of all equipment in columns `22` to `26` in `sheet 1` based of the address column.

In `sheet1` **column 3 Header Address** it shows different address that match address in `sheet 3` and in `column 22 to 26` it shows different types of **equipment Headers**.

Then below in the rows it says installed or new. I want to be able to have `sheet3 column 7` show a percentage of installed vs new from `columns 22 to 26 from sheet 1` based on the `address columns`

```
   =IFERROR(
      COUNTIFS(
      'CSH Test'!C[-4],[@Address],
      CSH_Test[[#All],[Document Scanner]:[Barcode Scanner]], "Installed"
) /
   countsifs(
           'CSH Test'!C[-4],[@Address],
            CSH_Test[[#All],[Document Scanner]:[Barcode Scanner]], "New"
),
```

This is what i had but that does not seem to work

[image: Sheet1]

[image]

Comment: Your COUNTIFS are not properly done.  COUNTIFS(rng,value,rng2,value2,...) you have 3 criteria.  You also have a typo `countsifs`

Comment: Please show some mock data and expected output.  You description and formula are not sufficient for us to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Also in addition to what Sir has said, you have a duplicate question, which you have already raised for review you could have waited for sometime, though there is no issue in asking the same question with different subject line. **[here_old_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482265/xlookup-then-divide-based-of-info)**

Comment: Sorry I got notified that first post was deleted that's why I have 2. I just added 2 pictures if you can see how the address match. Where it says epic equipment. I want that to pull a % installed vs new based of the address and all the equipment . I'm assuming i need to add an x or v lookup maybe but unsure. Please let me know if that clears up your questions. I can add the excel sheet if possible but not sure how I go about that.